# How can I make my graphic scroll horizontally to keep up with incoming data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The graphic below is the current output of my program, which is basically working. The problem is, it draws the graph from left to right, plotting the JSON data it receives, but then goes off the edge of the screen (or into the bit bucket), when what I want is for the graph to scroll to the left as the JSON data is consumed. You can see the data is cutoff past the "9" label.

I'm not sure where to begin making that happen and would appreciate some advice.

Current output:

[image]

```
function createLineChart(data, number) {
    var xy_chart = d3_xy_chart()
      .width(960)
      .height(500)
      .xlabel("TCS")
      .ylabel("STATUS");
    var svg = d3.select(".lineChart" + number).append("svg")
      .datum(data)
      .call(xy_chart);

    function d3_xy_chart() {
      var width = 640,
      height = 480,
      xlabel = "X Axis Label",
      ylabel = "Y Axis Label";


      function chart(selection, svg) {
        selection.each(function (datasets) {

//
// Create the plot.

          var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
          innerwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
          innerheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


          var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, innerwidth])
            .domain([d3.min(datasets, function (d) {
              return d3.min(d.x);
            }),
            d3.max(datasets, function (d) {
              return d3.max(d.x);
            })]);

// Set y scale

          var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([innerheight, 0])
            .domain([d3.min(datasets, function (d) {
              return d3.min(d.y);
            }),
            d3.max(datasets, function (d) {
              return d3.max(d.y);
            })]);

          var color_scale = d3.scale.category10()
            .domain(d3.range(datasets.length));

          var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x_scale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(function (d, i) {

// Remove remove decimal points and set values again to the x axis

              if (d % 1 == 0) {
                return parseInt(d)

              } else {
                return "  "

              }

            });

          var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y_scale)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(function (d, i) {

              if (d == "1") {
                return "NOT EXECUTED"
              } else if (d == "2") {
                return "FAILED"
              } else if (d == "3") {
                return "PASSED"
              } else {
               return "  "
              }

            });

          var x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x_scale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickSize(-innerheight)
            .tickFormat("");

          var y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y_scale)
            .orient("left")
            .tickSize(-innerwidth)
            .tickFormat("");

// Draw the line

         var draw_line = d3.svg.line()
           .interpolate("linear")
           .x(function (d) {
              return x_scale(d[0]);
           })
          .y(function (d) {
              return y_scale(d[1]);
           });

         var svg = d3.select(this)
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height)
           .append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Append g as x grid to svg

         svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "x grid")
           .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
           .call(x_grid);

         svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "y grid")
           .call(y_grid);

        svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "x axis")
           .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
           .call(x_axis)
           .append("text")
           .attr("dy", "-.71em")
           .attr("x", innerwidth)
           .style("text-anchor", "end")
           .text(xlabel);

// Append g as x axis to svg

        svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "y axis")
           .call(y_axis)
           .append("text")
           .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
           .attr("y", 6)
           .attr("dy", "0.71em")
           .style("text-anchor", "end")
           .text(ylabel);

         var data_lines = svg.selectAll(".d3_xy_chart_line")
           .data(datasets.map(function (d) {
                return d3.zip(d.x, d.y);
            }))
           .enter().append("g")
           .attr("class", "d3_xy_chart_line");


            data_lines.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return draw_line(d);
            })
            .attr("stroke", function (_, i) {
                 return color_scale(i);
           });

// Set label texts

           data_lines.append("text")
           .datum(function (d, i) {
               return {name: datasets[i].label, final: d[d.length - 1]};
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
               return ( "translate(" + x_scale(d.final[0]) + "," +
              y_scale(d.final[1]) + ")" );
            })
           .attr("x", 3)
           .attr("dy", ".35em")
           .attr("fill", function (_, i) {
               return color_scale(i);
           })
           .text(function (d) {
              return d.name;
           });


        });
    }

     chart.width = function (value) {
      if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = value;
        return chart;
     };

     chart.height = function (value) {
       if (!arguments.length) return height;
       height = value;
       return chart;
     };

     chart.xlabel = function (value) {
      if (!arguments.length) return xlabel;
        xlabel = value;
        return chart;
     };

     chart.ylabel = function (value) {
      if (!arguments.length) return ylabel;
       ylabel = value;
       return chart;
     };

     return chart;
    }


    }
```

Comment: You can see after the 9 value of x axis is continued further. But that data are nt displayed.  As a solution for that problem I am going to make this graph scrollable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make the x axis scrollable in a d3 line chart graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472470/how-to-make-the-x-axis-scrollable-in-a-d3-line-chart-graph)