# how to make the x axis scrollable in a d3 line chart graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Below is the code I used. This code is working fine to me, but problem is when the out put comes for the below code, some part of the graph doesn't show in x axis. Some parts are hidden because of the x axis length is not enough to show. So I decided to make this graph scrollable and also I tried a code to make this scrollable.But It didnt work.

please help me to sort out this.

I used this reference :- http://computationallyendowed.com/blog/2013/01/21/bounded-panning-in-d3.html

graph :

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div class="lineChart1" style=" overflow: scroll">
                 <svg width="960" height="500" style=" overflow: scroll"></svg>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
     function createLineChart() {


             var number=1;
             var data = [ { label: "Execution 1 - buddhika@gmail.com",
        x: ["1","2","2","3","3","4","4","5","5","6","6","7","7","8","8","9","9","10","10","11","11","12","12"],
        y: ["3","3","3","3","3","3","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","2","3","3","3","3"] }] ;


        var xy_chart = d3_xy_chart()
                .width(960)
                .height(500)
                .xlabel("TCS")
                .ylabel("STATUS");
        var svg = d3.select(".lineChart" + number).append("svg")
                .datum(data)
                .call(xy_chart);






        function d3_xy_chart() {
            var width = 640,
                    height = 480,
                    xlabel = "X Axis Label",
                    ylabel = "Y Axis Label";


            function chart(selection, svg) {
                selection.each(function (datasets) {
                    //
                    // Create the plot.
                    //
                    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                            innerwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
                            innerheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


                    var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .range([0, innerwidth])
                            .domain([d3.min(datasets, function (d) {
                                return d3.min(d.x);
                            }),
                                d3.max(datasets, function (d) {
                                    return d3.max(d.x);
                                })]);


                    var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .range([innerheight, 0])
                            .domain([d3.min(datasets, function (d) {
                                return d3.min(d.y);
                            }),
                                d3.max(datasets, function (d) {
                                    return d3.max(d.y);
                                })]);



                    var color_scale = d3.scale.category10()
                            .domain(d3.range(datasets.length));

                    var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(x_scale)
                            .orient("bottom")
                            .tickFormat(function (d, i) {

                                if (d % 1 == 0) {

                                    return parseInt(d)

                                } else {

                                    return "  "

                                }

                            });

                    var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(y_scale)
                            .orient("left")
                            .tickFormat(function (d, i) {

                                if (d == "1") {

                                    return "NOT EXECUTED"

                                } else if (d == "2") {

                                    return "FAILED"

                                } else if (d == "3") {

                                    return "PASSED"

                                } else {

                                    return "  "

                                }

                            });


                    var x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(x_scale)
                            .orient("bottom")
                            .tickSize(-innerheight)
                            .tickFormat("");

                    var y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(y_scale)
                            .orient("left")
                            .tickSize(-innerwidth)
                            .tickFormat("");

                    var draw_line = d3.svg.line()
                            .interpolate("linear")
                            .x(function (d) {
                                return x_scale(d[0]);
                            })
                            .y(function (d) {
                                return y_scale(d[1]);
                            });

                    var svg = d3.select(this)
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("height", height)
                            .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                    svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "x grid")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
                            .call(x_grid);

                    svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "y grid")
                            .call(y_grid);

                    svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "x axis")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
                            .call(x_axis)
                            .append("text")
                            .attr("dy", "-.71em")
                            .attr("x", innerwidth)
                            .style("text-anchor", "end")
                            .text(xlabel);

                    svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "y axis")
                            .call(y_axis)
                            .append("text")
                            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                            .attr("y", 6)
                            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                            .style("text-anchor", "end")
                            .text(ylabel);

                    var data_lines = svg.selectAll(".d3_xy_chart_line")
                            .data(datasets.map(function (d) {
                                return d3.zip(d.x, d.y);
                            }))
                            .enter().append("g")
                            .attr("class", "d3_xy_chart_line");


                    data_lines.append("path")
                            .attr("class", "line")
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                                return draw_line(d);
                            })
                            .attr("stroke", function (_, i) {
                                return color_scale(i);
                            });

                    data_lines.append("text")
                            .datum(function (d, i) {
                                return {name: datasets[i].label, final: d[d.length - 1]};
                            })
                            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                return ( "translate(" + x_scale(d.final[0]) + "," +
                                y_scale(d.final[1]) + ")" );
                            })
                            .attr("x", 3)
                            .attr("dy", ".35em")
                            .attr("fill", function (_, i) {
                                return color_scale(i);
                            })
                            .text(function (d) {
                                return d.name;
                            });
```

// scrolling code START

```
              var xscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 12]).range([0, 12]),
                            yscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([innerheight, 0]);

                    var line = d3.svg.line()
                            .x(function(d) { return xscale(d[0]); })
                            .y(function(d) { return yscale(d[1]); })
                            .interpolate('basis');

                    svg.append('g')
                            .datum(datasets)
                            .append('path')
                            .attr('class', 'data')
                            .attr('d', line);


                    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                            .scaleExtent([1, 1])
                            .x(xscale)
                            .on('zoom', function() {
                                svg.select('.data').attr('d', line)
                            });

                    svg.call(zoom);
```

// Scrolling code END

```
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the issue in here. issue is in json data what you provided. that all json data stored as strings not as integers. all integer numbers with in the double quotes. that mean it become as a string. when the max number taking for the x axis from the json data, it take the 9 as max number. it happen because 9 is the max number when numbers are strings. because of that graph not going to continue after 9. but expected value is 12. no need the scrolling code here. simply can make the graph scrollable by adding css entry in div ("overflow: scroll")